# Display Code as Text in UITextView

Tags: ios, uitextview

I'm trying to display some java code in a UITextView, but I can't seem to create the same sort of hanging indentation that happens when coding in an IDE. Is there a simple way to do this, or will I have to mess around with Core Text in order to achieve this? How could it be achieved?

Comment: @JAL I guess that helps enough to merit redirecting to it. They aren't quite the same question as there is no user typing in this question, just text display.

Comment: Oh sorry about that.  To display text indented, you're going to want to use the ASCII escape characters.  Check out this example: `yourTextView.text = @"public class Greeter {\n\tpublic static void main(String[] args) {\n\t\tSystem.out.println(\"Hello World!\");\n\t}\n}"`

Comment: Its ok, I think that the suggested duplicate provides enough information to solve the problem.